# building a PHP router

Tags: php, url-routing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [turn URL route into funciton arguments php mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111358/turn-url-route-into-funciton-arguments-php-mvc)
>   [CMS Routing in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770104/cms-routing-in-mvc)

I'm currently trying to rewrite a PHP router.

The new htaccess rewrite has the follows.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/index.php?url=$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Whilst in index.php in `public`, I am getting the URL using the `$url = $_GET['url'];`

What I need to do is to pass `$url` to the Router function:: `route($url)`

If a URL is passed as : /page/function/$params which would then translate as : `index.php?url=page/xapp/function`, I'd need to map and route to Controller `xapp` and call `function($params)`.

By this time, the autoloader has already been called.  I'd also need to set a default function to be called if only /page/ is called.

How would I achieve this in a router?

Comment: or [Is this a good way to match URI to class/method in PHP for MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033318/is-this-a-good-way-to-match-uri-to-class-method-in-php-for-mvc)

Comment: You may try this router package too, https://github.com/miladrahimi/phprouter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should check out the code of [klein.php](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php), a small php router.
I think you should figure it from that solution.

If not, check out also **slim** [here](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim)